# Where can I find a CSS / javascript solution to placeholder labels in input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have something that works like the login box on windows live.  Boxes where I see a label inside and then the label disappears when the user starts typing.

All I can find is solutions that use jQuery. Does anyone know of some javascript/CSS solutions that do not require me to load jQuery? I mean something other than the placeholder attribute in HTML5. I want something that will work in most browswers not just the new ones.

Comment: *Most* browsers support `placeholder` actually: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: IE<10 still has a pretty respectable [share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201301-201301-bar). Thankfully this seems to be improving fast.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills
For most of these plugins you can just strip out the jquery part and use it as standalone

Comment: all of the event binding and class checks will use jQuery which makes stripping it out painful IMHO.

Comment: [Placeholder.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) doesn't require jquery

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 placeholder polyfills that don't depend on other libraries:

- [placeholder-fixer](http://code.google.com/p/placeholder-fixer/)
- [Placeholders.js](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js)

Comment: It took 470 lines to do what I wrote I 20 lines, of course this solution is much more robust and feature complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll your own... Here's a JSFiddle I through together. http://jsfiddle.net/VF8Dr/

CSS

```
.placeholder { 
  color: gray; 
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
function addPlaceholder(id, text) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(id);
  var ph = document.createElement("SPAN");
  ph.className = "placeholder";
  ph.innerHTML = text;
  elm.parentNode.insertBefore(ph, elm.nextSibling);
  ph.style.left = elm.offsetLeft + 'px';
  ph.style.top = elm.offsetTop + 'px';
  ph.onclick = function() {
    ph.style.display = 'none';
    elm.focus();
  };
  elm.onfocus = function() {
    if(ph.style.display != 'none')
      ph.style.display = 'none';
  };
  elm.onblur = function() {
    if(elm.value == '')
      ph.style.display = '';
  };
}
addPlaceholder("demo", "my text");
```

Obviously, it's not extensively tested, but if you are stubborn about not using a framework like jQuery (or just avoiding unneeded bloat) but still want cross-browser and old-browser compatibility this will help you get there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in the past:

```
activatePlaceHolder: function() {
    var detect = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
    if (detect.indexOf("msie") < 0) return false;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var inputLen = inputs.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputLen; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "text") {
            if (inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder") && inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder").length > 0) {
                inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder");
                inputs[i].onclick = function() {
                    if (this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder")) {
                        this.value = "";
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                inputs[i].onblur = function() {
                    if (this.value.length < 1) {
                        this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: You'd probably also need to add an event on form submit to clear any text boxes that have their placeholder as a value.